# Partial transpose of SQL results

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with columns:

```
ID, N, S, E, W
```

I can easily retrieve a single row of this table with a SELECT

```
SELECT ID, N, S, E, W from {table name} where ID = 'xxx'
```

Giving me

```
ID, N, S, E, W
```

However, I would like my results for each ID formatted like this:

```
ID, N, W, 1
ID, N, E, 2
ID, S, E, 3
ID, S, W, 4
```

In my case, N & S are latitudes, E & W are longitudes, and {N, S, E, W} defines a square in my system. I want to return a point list with a winding order so I can draw them later.

My flavor of SQL is AWS Redshift.

My table is large, so execution speed is a concern. What is an elegant solution?

Comment: what are 1,2,3,4 at the end ?

Comment: That is the winding order of the points to draw a square, it's clockwise. I think the answer will be almost the same without it, since it probably just gets UNIONed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution would be:

```
select id, n, w, 1 from your_table where ID = 'xxx' union all
select id, n, e, 2 from your_table where ID = 'xxx' union all
select id, s, e, 3 from your_table where ID = 'xxx' union all
select id, s, w, 4 from your_table where ID = 'xxx';
```

I am not sure if Redshift supports `left join lateral` like postgres, but if it does then you can use:

```
select t.id, x.*
from your_table t
left join lateral (
    values  (n, w, 1), (n, e, 2),
            (s, e, 3), (s, w, 4)
) x (col1, col2, col3) on true
```

Answer (score 2):

Ugly, but does the job:

```
SELECT ID, N as Col1, W as Col2, 1 as Col3 from {table name} where ID = 'xxx'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, N as Col1, E as Col2, 2 as Col3 from {table name} where ID = 'xxx'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, S as Col1, E as Col2, 3 as Col3 from {table name} where ID = 'xxx'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, S as Col1, W as Col2, 4 as Col3 from {table name} where ID = 'xxx'
```